# How to implement password validation in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have requirement of password validation ,which is to display message Ex: number character exceed,do not match .

Comment: Using a class that inherits from a `ContentPage` you can call `ShowAlertDialog("Alert", "Number character exceed", "ok");` and to check that you can use an Entry and it's text property`Entry.Text.Count`

Comment: Where do you want to display the error? On a dialog or on a Label nearby the password Entry element?

Comment: There is no magic (or built-in) way to do this.  You just add custom validation logic in your code behind (or view model) and execute it on a Button click (or whatever).

Comment: I have two entry 1:Password, 2:Re-enter Password , when Re -enter password is  entered ,i need to validate the password and Re-enter password data and to display message on Label ,without using Button click in Xamarin.forms.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Xamarin.Forms 1.3 you should definitely use Behaviours, if not you should upgrade anyway :)

There is a nice blog post with code example here: http://blog.xamarin.com/behaviors-in-xamarin.forms/

Comment: You are welcome! If you think this is the right one please accept this answer